How to Fix CancellationException When Asynchronously Uploading Files to S3 with AWS SDK for Java?
I am working on uploading file content to AWS S3 using the AWS SDK for Java. Since the file is created after compressing original data, I don't know its size beforehand.
I'm following the AWS documentation example for uploading streams to S3:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_Scenario_UploadStream_section.html
    BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody body =
        AsyncRequestBody.forBlockingInputStream(null); // 'null' indicates a stream will be provided later.

    CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> responseFuture =
        s33CrtAsyncClient.putObject(r -> r.bucket(bucketName).key(key), body);

    // AsyncExampleUtils.randomString() returns a random string up to 100 characters.
    String randomString = AsyncExampleUtils.randomString();
    logger.info("random string to upload: {}: length={}", randomString, randomString.length());

    // Provide the stream of data to be uploaded.
    body.writeInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(randomString.getBytes()));

    PutObjectResponse response = responseFuture.join(); // Wait for the response.

However, when I execute the code, I encounter the following error:
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: subscription has been cancelled.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.async.SimplePublisher.lambda$doProcessQueue$9(SimplePublisher.java:286)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.async.SimplePublisher$FailureMessage.get(SimplePublisher.java:413)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.async.SimplePublisher$FailureMessage.access$700(SimplePublisher.java:397)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.async.SimplePublisher.doProcessQueue(SimplePublisher.java:260)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.async.SimplePublisher.processEventQueue(SimplePublisher.java:224)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.async.SimplePublisher.send(SimplePublisher.java:128)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.async.InputStreamConsumingPublisher.doBlockingWrite(InputStreamConsumingPublisher.java:58)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody.writeInputStream(BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody.java:95)


How can I fix this?
Environment:

AWS SDK version: 2.28.7
AWS CRT version: 0.33.2
Java version: 17


It looks like the issue arises because of how the S3AsyncClient is being created. The CancellationException can occur when the client is not set up to handle certain kinds of asynchronous operations effectively.
Instead of using the standard builder:
    return S3AsyncClient.builder()
        .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
        .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
        .build();

You should use the crtBuilder, which is better suited for handling asynchronous tasks, especially if you are dealing with features like S3 transfer acceleration:
    return S3AsyncClient.crtBuilder()
        .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
        .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
        .build();

By using crtBuilder(), you leverage the AWS Common Runtime (CRT) library, which provides advanced functionalities and optimizes certain network operations for better performance and resilience.
